# How to explicitly derive the Hamiltonian for a Scalar Field in quantum field theory?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, hamiltonian, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The most general scalar field defined at all points of a Minkowski spacetime can be modelled as;
$$\phi({\bf{x}}, t) = \Sigma_{{\bf{k}}} \left(a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}}u_{{\bf{k}}} + a_{{\bf{k}}}u^{*}_{{\bf{k}}}\right)$$
where $$u_{{\bf{k}}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega (2 \pi)^3\vphantom{\tfrac{1}{2}}}} e^{i{\bf{k}\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{2}}} \cdot {\bf{x}} - i \omega t}.$$
The energy density is given by;
$$T_{tt} = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)^2 + \Sigma_{i}\left (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 + m^2 \phi^2\right]$$
My attempt at solving follows;
\begin{align}
T_{tt} &= \Sigma_{{\bf{k}}} \frac{1}{2}\left[(-i \omega (a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}}u_{{\bf{k}}} - a_{{\bf{k}}}u^{*}_{{\bf{k}}}))^2 + (ik_1 (a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}}u_{{\bf{k}}} - a_{{\bf{k}}}u^{*}_{{\bf{k}}}))^2 + (ik_2 (…))^2 + (ik_3 (…))^2 + m^2(\phi^2)\right]\\
&= \Sigma_{{\bf{k}}} \frac{1}{2}(-\omega^2 (a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} (u_{{\bf{k}}})^2 - a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a_{{\bf{k}}} - a_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} + a_{{\bf{k}}} a_{{\bf{k}}}(u^{*}_{{\bf{k}}})^2) + |{\bf{k}}^2|(-a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} (u_{{\bf{k}}})^2 + a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a_{{\bf{k}}} + a_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} - a_{{\bf{k}}} a_{{\bf{k}}}(u^{*}_{{\bf{k}}})^2) + m^2 (a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} (u_{{\bf{k}}})^2 + a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a_{{\bf{k}}} + a_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} + a_{{\bf{k}}} a_{{\bf{k}}}(u^{*}_{{\bf{k}}})^2)
\end{align}
To get the Hamiltonian, an integral must be performed over all space, and using the identity $\omega^2 = |{\bf{k}}|^2 + m^2$, the integral can be split into its linear components;
$$\Sigma_{{\bf{k}}} \bigg(\int \frac{-|{\bf{k}}|^2}{2 (2\pi)^3 \omega} (a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} (u_{{\bf{k}}})^2 + a_{{\bf{k}}}a_{{\bf{k}}} (u^{*}_{{\bf{k}}})^2) d^3x+ \int \frac{\omega}{2 (2\pi)^3} (a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a_{{\bf{k}}} + a_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}})d^3x\bigg)$$
I identify the first part to be zero as it is just the Dirac delta function, forcing $|{\bf{k}}|^2 = 0$, but I am completely lost how to do the second part, which is the final step to get the Hamiltonian;
$$H = \frac{1}{2} \Sigma_{{\bf{k}}} \bigg[ (a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}} a_{{\bf{k}}} + a_{{\bf{k}}} a^{\dagger}_{{\bf{k}}})\omega \bigg]$$
What mistake have I made? I suspect I have overlooked either the intergal or the squaring tthe fields themselves, where I assumed mixed $k$ terms would be trivial.
Thanks

Comment: Your $H$ isn’t correct.

Comment: Thank you, fixed(For future reference; forgot an $\omega$ )

Answer (score 1):

You are actually correct as that was the Hamiltonian you should have got. To get the desired relation use the canonical commutation relation between the ladder operators. You should then get
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_k w_k\hat{a}^{\dagger}_k \hat{a}_k + \frac{1}{2} \sum_k w_k
\end{equation}
If the momenta is continuous this last term is divergent. However, note that the last term doesn't depend on any operators and is actually the ground state energy of many oscillators occupying your space. This term can then be neglected as in QFT, we don't observe absolute energies but energy differences. Since this last term is there for every state, we can just shift the Hamiltonian so that the ground state has 0 energy.

This issue of sum over all modes comes up a lot in QFT calculations. The removal of this type of infinity is done via a procedure called "normal ordering". What we mean by normal ordering is given an operator, we put all raising operators to the left and lowering operators to the right. This way, we get rid of weird infinities that crop up and doesn't really mean anything physically.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful analysis of the zero-point enegy, but unfortunately, my confusion is a lot more trivial; I was wondering why I arrived at an equation; $\int \frac{1}{2 (2 \pi)^3} d^3x$ which I don't know how to progress to get the general Hamiltonian in the first place, and then the fun of vacuum phenomena can begin

Comment: Ah I see your issue. You should have started with summation of two different wavevectors $k$ and $q$ and eliminate the $q$ dependence using canonical commutation relations for the raising and lowering operators